# Bash: convert to lowercase, BUT preserve the case of the first letter of every word

Tags: bash, case

I searched for this repeatedly but I couldn't find an answer for this specific scenario. I'd like to be able to convert a string to lowercase while also preserving any existing titled words.

For example:

```
Hello, this is a Titled woRd aND ThIs one is UPPERCASED.
```

should become:

```
Hello, this is a Titled word and This one is Uppercased.
```

Every letter would be lowercased, except the first letter of each word would keep its case. I'm familiar with the common forms of changing case but not something this specific. Not to be confused with Title case, as that is not what I'm asking here. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { printf "%s",substr($i,1,1);for(j=2;j<=length($i);j++) { printf "%s",tolower(substr($i,j,1))} printf "%s"," " } }' <<< "Hello, this is a Titled woRd aND ThIs one is UPPERCASED."
```

Explanation:

```
awk '{ 
       for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {                           # Loop on each word
          printf "%s",substr($i,1,1);                  # Print the first letter in the word
          for(j=2;j<=length($i);j++) {  
            printf "%s",tolower(substr($i,j,1))        # Loop on the rest of the letters in the word and print in lower case
          }  
       printf "%s"," "                                 # Print a space
       } 
     }' <<< "Hello, this is a Titled woRd aND ThIs one is UPPERCASED."
```

Using bash:

```
for var in $(echo "Hello, this is a Titled woRd aND ThIs one is UPPERCASED.");
do 
   printf "%s" ${var:0:1};             # Print the first letter of the word
   var1=${var:1};                      # Read the rest of the word into var1
   printf "%s " "${var1,,[$var1]}";    # Convert vars into lowercase and print
done
```

Comment: Thanks, the awk version works perfectly and the comments are very helpful for understanding the logic behind what is happening. Wow, it's amazing how many things you can do in the shell. Your pure bash version makes me feel like I should have been able to figure that out, although to be honest I don't know that I would have thought to loop through the string like that.

Comment: The pure Bash version in this answer can misbehave if the string contains `*` or `?` (since it will interpret those as globs). Also, it will replace any sequence of whitespace with a single space, and remove leading and trailing whitespace. So I think the Awk version is better.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you need a pure `bash` solution, but using some commonly available utilities makes life easier.

Using `awk`:

```
$ echo 'Hello, this is a Titled woRd aND ThIs one is UPPERCASED.' | \
    awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){$i=substr($i,1,1)tolower(substr($i,2))}}1'
Hello, this is a Titled word and This one is Uppercased.
```

It simply iterates over all fields (space-separated) and assigns to each field (`$i`) the first letter of that field, followed by a downcased copy of the remainder of the field.

Using GNU `sed` (less portable, but perhaps more readable):

```
$ echo 'Hello, this is a Titled woRd aND ThIs one is UPPERCASED.' | \
    sed -r 's/\b(\w)(\w*)/\1\L\2/g'
Hello, this is a Titled word and This one is Uppercased.
```

This matches a word boundary (`\b`) followed by a letter (word character, `\w`) and then zero or more letters (`\w*`). It replaces this by the first letter (`\1`), followed by the lowercased version (`\L`) of the remaining letters (`\2`).

Comment: The awk version worked well and is more condensed than the other answer. It's plenty sufficient for my use case and I thank you very much. I will say that I didn't have luck with the sed version. Could it be because I'm using sed on a Mac as opposed to Linux? The version I have says 11.1 located here `/usr/bin/sed`

Comment: I tried using gnu-sed and it worked, so it was due to my Mac copy.

Comment: Yep, I didn't write "GNU `sed`" and "less portable" for nothing :)